# Conditional checking between two int objects

Tags: python, recursion, conditional-statements

I am iterating in a for loop, constructing a list, whilst comparing the last number of that list with another number.

I would like my code to see if the last item of the list is smaller than the item it is being compared to, and if it is, to add it to the end of its list and then to continue.

if the last item of the list is larger, i would like to pop off the last item of the list. i would then like to subject it to the same conditionals.

here is my code, it is not working, it wont re check the conditionals after popping off the last item of the list.

```
if tempList:
    lastNum=tempList[-1]
    #############################################
    if element < lastNum:
        incList.append(tempList)
        tempList.pop()
        lastNum=tempList[-1]
   #############################################

    elif lastNum < element:                                               
        tempList.append(element)
        continue
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Could you add an example input, the output you get, and the output you would like to get instead?

Comment: I'm also not sure what you are trying to do, but I notice you are appending `tempList`, which is the entire list - I assume this should be `element` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can bundle this into a function:

```
def append_if_lower_else_pop_end_from_list_until_lower(l, num):
    """Add num to l if l[-1] < num, else pop() from l until"""
    while l and l[-1] > num:
        l.pop()
    l.append(num)

    # this is not strictly needed - lists are mutable so you are mutating it
    # returning it would only make sense for chaining off it with other methods
    return l 

k = [3,5,7,9,11,13]
print(k)
append_if_lower_else_pop_end_from_list_until_lower(k, 10)
print(k)
append_if_lower_else_pop_end_from_list_until_lower(k, 6)
print(k)
append_if_lower_else_pop_end_from_list_until_lower(k, 10)
print(k)
append_if_lower_else_pop_end_from_list_until_lower(k, 10)
print(k)
append_if_lower_else_pop_end_from_list_until_lower(k, -10)
print(k)
```

Output:

```
[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13]  # start
[3, 5, 7, 9, 10]      # after adding 10
[3, 5, 6]             # after addding 6
[3, 5, 6, 10]         # after adding 10
[3, 5, 6, 10, 10]     # after adding 10 again
[-10]                 # after adding -10
```

---

Why return the list as well: example for chaining:

```
k = [3,5,17,9,11,13]
append_if_lower_else_pop_end_from_list_until_lower(k, 10).sort()
print(k)
```

Output:

```
[3, 5, 9, 10, 17]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out:

```
yourlist = [3,1,4]
n = 1
resultlist = yourlist[:-1] if yourlist[-1]>=n else yourlist+[n]
print(resultlist)
n = 5
resultlist = yourlist[:-1] if yourlist[-1]>=n else yourlist+[n]
print(resultlist)
```

Output:
[3,1]

[3,1,4,5]